# Adding a prototype cell to a table view in storyboard makes navigation bar title small

Tags: swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a View Controller which segues from a previous controller that has large titles. The navigation bar in the navigation controller has the Prefers Large Titles checkbox checked.

I have added a Table View to this new view controller. Until then, the title remains large. However as soon as I add prototype cells to the table view, the navigation bar becomes small.

In code I added this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
}
```

The problem is, when the view controller comes into view, the title appears small for a second and then immediately shifts to large title.

How can I fix it so that it appear large as I segue and avoid that size shift once the title becomes visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is a feature: when the user scroll, the large Title will disappear and show small title on top.

your problem happend because in the xib file:
your layout is small title and its change to largeTitle when it pushed.
but the view doesn't know that.

to fix this you just need to call: view.layoutIfNeeded() in the viewDidLoad() method.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = "Large title"
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```